# How to skip some products to addtocart when reorder in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, reorder

I want to skip some products whenever reorder. file path in vendor folder (vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/AbstractController/Reorder.php:57) and it is an abstract Class.

I want simply add this code condition. 
 **if($item->getSku() != 'offer123')** 
Is it possible by plugin ?

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
   if($item->getSku() != 'offer123'){ // i want to apply this condition 
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNotice($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
}
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code. It is working for me.

File: etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
    <plugin name="custom_skip_product_addtocart" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Cart" sortOrder="100"/>
</type>
```

Then create following file in your module.

File: Plugin/Cart.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class Cart
{
    public function aroundAddOrderItem($subject, callable $proceed, $orderItem, $qtyFlag = null)
    {
        if ($orderItem->getParentItem() === null) {
            $sku = $orderItem->getSku();
            if(in_array($sku, ['WT08-XS-Black']))
            {
                return $this;
            }
            else
            {
                return $proceed($orderItem, $qtyFlag);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: Hi Yash7690 It's working perfect :-) , Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thats great !!! Cheers !!!